# ember.js clickable links inside clickable div

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've found a few answers for this specific to jQuery but nothing related to Ember.Js. I'm pretty new to Ember so I may be missing something obvious so my bad if so.

I've created a clickable div using an action inside my controller like so:

```
goHere: function(article) {
    this.transitionTo('view-article',{article_id: article.article_id});
}
```

But now my anchors inside of that div don't work. Any idea how to get around this?

EDIT: I can't show you all of the code because it's a huge project, but basically we have Topics, in each Topic is a series of Articles. The Articles are listed on the homepage like so:

```
<div class="article pull-left span10"{{action goHere this}} >
    ...
    <a href="url.com">XX</a>
    ...
</div>
```

And that anchor tag, when clicked, triggers the goHere action instead of redirecting to url.com

Comment: Can you show more code? Like the controller, template, route etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
goHere: function(article) {
    this.transitionToRoute('view-article',article);
}
```

If that doesn't work a jsbin/jsfiddle would be helpful for more context.

See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute

Answer (score 2):

Using transitionTo in controller is deprecated but it should work with depreciation warning.
Using transitionToRoute (as in @RyanHirsch answer) is the right way to do that.

You can better use linkTo helper

```
   {{#linkTo 'view-article' model_to_be_passed}}Go to View Article {{/linkTo}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using links entered by the user, which were turned into anchor tags by rails_autolink on the server, so I wasn't able to replace the links with ember link-to.

I was able to work around this with a few steps. First, I added the class `autolink` to all the links I was generating with autolink. Then in the Ember action for the surrounding div, I did:

```
if event.target.className == 'autolink'
    @send('handleAutolink')
else
    // (handle non-link click)
```

Then on the ApplicationRoute, I put in a handler for the handleAutolink action that basically cancels the ember action and opens the link with javascript:

```
handleAutolink: ->
  event.preventDefault()
  window.open(event.target.href, '_blank')
```

I realize this is probably a giant hack, but I'd be happy to hear another approach!